# How to determine which program accessed the Mac Camera?

Tags: access-control, macos, process

The green light on my laptop's camera just flashed on and then off after 1 second. I am extremely concerned about this since I am not running any programs which could have enabled the camera.

I checked Console.app and found only this:

```
AppleCamIn::power_on_hardware
```

In `Sharing` settings, I only had `File Sharing` enabled for my Public folder, which is empty (I've since disabled the setting).

Is there a way to see which process requested camera access? I am worried my laptop has been compromised. I'm running Apple Yosemite, the latest stable version.

Comment: I address this by being so ugly that people immediately shut off the camera after they see what's on it, personally.

Comment: [Micro Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html) just for that (built by a company behind Little Snitch).

Answer (score 4):

Both Debian and BSD you can use `lsof` command.

In your articular case, you can run:

lsof | grep -i "AppleCamera"

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) of lsof related to your OS.

Comment: Works also for OS X

Comment: Am on BigSur and this brings up nothing yet camera light is on

Comment: My setup is I have mmhmmCamera app which Telegram uses. So telegram kept the camera light on after a call but "AppleCamera" does not show in lsof. "Cemera" did but only because mmHmm uses that in their app name. So this method is not reliable on macOS - at least not on BigSur.